# 3com VCX - how to get a dump of outgoing phone calls

Tags: voip, 3com

I am looking (hoping) for a way to dump a list of all outgoing calls from the VCX for a time period?    Possible via the web interface, or via the ssh interface.

For example, we need the date (time would be nice), and the dialed phone number for 10/1/2012 - 12/29/2012.

This is a 3Com VCX 7000 system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The files are stored on XML files under /opt/3com/VCX/ acctxml or bssxml , in the format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.XML. copy the files to a new folder, and then point the  VCX cdrapp at that folder.

Let me know if you don't have the app.

Comment: I do not have the app

Comment: Here it is.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fe64jwvq8uflx3f/VCXCDR_R8_2_1.exe